# Replace row col in bootstrap with another row with JQuery and fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with columns in bootstrap, but i want to hide it in 10 seconds and replace it with another row of columns with a fade.

My html code is:

```
<div class="row">       
    <div class="sponsorsimg" id="foo">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c1" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c2" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c3" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c4" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c5" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c6" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i want to replace (fade) in 10 seconds with:

```
<div class="row">     
    <div class="sponsorsimg" id="foo2" style="display: none;"">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c1" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c2" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c3" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c4" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c5" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-lg-2">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="images/c6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="c6" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: 10 seconds after what event?

Comment: How is the new HTML obtained?

Comment: 10 seconds after bodyonload, or document get ready. The new html that i want to replace is the second code.

Comment: What Roamer meant was: Do you have the replacement as a separate html file that has to be loaded from server or do you want to generate it from scratch in javascript or do yo already have it hidden in your html or...?

Comment: Also: Do you already have some javascript you wrote yourself? It would help a lot if you could post what work you already did and where you ran into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's the JSFiddle for this.](http://jsfiddle.net/ak4pxunv/2/) I would suggest having one piece of code and fading in and out your images, as opposed to all of your HTML. This code puts a CSS transition on bootstrap's `collapse` class, and when that class is toggled, the images fade in by setting the `opacity` to 1.

Use this HTML:

```
<div>
    <img class="togglingimage twosecondfade" src="http://i.imgur.com/mIi9fAs.jpg"/>
    <img class="togglingimage twosecondfade" src="http://i.imgur.com/LLh5tTS.jpg"/>
    <img class="togglingimage twosecondfade collapse" src="http://i.imgur.com/4x1yqLu.jpg"/>
    <img class="togglingimage twosecondfade collapse" src="http://i.imgur.com/v6ydmmQ.jpg"/>
</div>
```

With this Javascript:

```
var timeUntilTransition = 1000;

function toggleRows() {
    $(".togglingimage").toggleClass("collapse");
}

window.setTimeout(function () {
    toggleRows();
}, timeUntilTransition);
```

And this CSS:

```
@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css');
.twosecondfade
{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2.00s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2.00s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 2.00s linear;
    transition: opacity 2.00s linear;
}
.togglingimage.collapse
{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, the HTML doesn't need to be replaced. A cross-fade on each of the six images will do the job.

Comment: And if i want to display more than two rows? Instead of two rows using toggle, 3 or four different rows.

Comment: I'm implementing in my site but i have a problem, because the row that is hidden left a blank space, because is hidden but it saves the height, so it's showing a blank space until the another element disappear and the second element appear, how i can  fix it?

Comment: If i put a display: none in the toggling-image.collapse it works, but it not showing the fade with the opacity, it appears instantly... Is there any option to fade with the display or something? Thanks.

Comment: @Peter Yeah, I noticed that. [Use this fiddle instead.](http://jsfiddle.net/ak4pxunv/17/) Once we get one that works for you, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understood your second to last comment, but I think you either have to set height: 0 or display:none. And display:none doesn't work with transitions because css is a wonderful language /sarcasm.

Comment: I fixed it by a different way, apply      opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-timing-function: linear, step-end; in the togglingimage.collapse ;)

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it working. I'll try to update the answer with the working solution. @Peter